# Where is VSCode 1.70.3?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-7

[This page](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70) mentions VSCode 1.70.3 is the last release supporting Windows 7.

There's no download for that version listed at [uptodown](https://visual-studio-code.en.uptodown.com/windows/versions), and there's no tag for it in the [github repository](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tags?after=1.71.2).

Where I can I download that version?  What changed in it compared to 1.70.2 (e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73750995/589059) hints possibly something about PID in debug windows?), and where can I download the source code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out I’m not the only one curious about this.

Firstly, my guess is that VSCode @1.70.3 is a version exclusive to Windows 7. It adds a “stop updating” notification and no longer automatically checks for new versions, so we can’t get it through normal channels.

In other words, only when installing a version lower than 1.70.2 on Windows 7 will it automatically upgrade to 1.70.3, but that’s not what we want because it’s not an installation package. However, this also allowed me to obtain some version information, so we have the official download link.

---

VSCode 1.70.3

x64 - https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/a21a160d630530476218b85db95b0fd2a8cd1230/VSCodeSetup-x64-1.70.3.exe

x86 - https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/a21a160d630530476218b85db95b0fd2a8cd1230/VSCodeSetup-ia32-1.70.3.exe

Arm64 - https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/a21a160d630530476218b85db95b0fd2a8cd1230/VSCodeSetup-arm64-1.70.3.exe

Comment: Works seamlessly. Plus, the User version (no elevation during setup) can be obtained by replacing `Setup` with `UserSetup` in each link above.

Answer (score 3):

Above have gave the installer version.

Addition, here is the zip version of x86 of 1.70.3:

https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/a21a160d630530476218b85db95b0fd2a8cd1230/VSCode-win32-ia32-1.70.3.zip

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just Install 1.70.2 and update it to 1.70.3

Answer (score -2):

I know it's not 1.70.3 and is 1.70.2, but still ... better than nothing :)

[Visual Studio Code (64bit) 1.70.2](https://www.filepuma.com/download/visual_studio_code_64bit_1.70.2-32996/)

Comment: Note that version 1.70.2 is already available from the official download location linked in the question. There is absolutely no need to download it from an unofficial third party.